# MySQL Python Connector Failure

Tags: python, mysql

I have installed Python 3.7 64-bit on my 64-bit OS. I have also Installed mysql-installer-community-8.0.15.0 plus I installed MySQL connector using this code `python -m pip install mysql-connector` and still when I try to import mysql.connector. I get this error.

> "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\newprj\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
> "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/newprj/app.py" Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/newprj/app.py", line 1, in 
> import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

In addition, I installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.15-py3.7-windows-x86-64bit as well on my machine.
Please help me solve this problem, I have tried all possible things I could. Thank you

edit:
Used the following codes to install mysql.connector

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>python -m pip install mysql-connector
```

and

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

using pip3 I get this message:

> Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector in C:\users\test
> \appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
> <2.1.6>

and again when I go to pycharm and import mysql.connector I get above stated message no module 'mysql' found

edit after 2 hours:
No answers, I tried this. I uninstalled everything, python, mysql, pychar and reinstalled. Again the same problem. SHOULD I CHANGE MY COMPUTER?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124201/4758119

Comment: I have tried that before asking this question, no result

Comment: when i import mysql connector on python 3.7.2 shell, there isn't any error, but when I try the import mysql connector on pycharm it shows above stated error

Comment: give a try by installing through `pip3`

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are importing it

Comment: Seems like it's installed for another version of python

Comment: Do you have multiple versions installed?

Comment: @RahilHastu I tried to install through pip3 using `pip3 install mysql-connector` and it shows this message: Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector in c:\users\basir payenda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages

Comment: Before I had installed python 3.7 32-bit then I uninstalled it and reinstall its 64-bit version

Comment: @Asif can you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I used this code: import mysql.connector

Comment: it is just one line code: 

import mysql.connector

Comment: and I get above stated error. It has been 1.5 days I am trying to solve this issue looking youtube videos and ... nothing worked lol

Answer (score 0):

I think a new module in pycharm can not load automatically in pycharm projects interpreter, so you should try to create a new virtualenv project or change some configuration in project interpreter with these additional configuration. see my picture below:

1. With change existing project interpreter setting:
   goto **(File->Setting->Project: YourProjectName->Project Interpreter-> click on "+" in the right side->type name of module which you want to install.**

or

2. With create new project environtment and append additional setting:
   goto **(File->New Project->Project Interpreter: New Virtual Environment->Make sure the "base interpreter" path is correct->checklist "Inherit global site-packages" to load all of module which you have been installed before)**

Answer (score -1):

Try to activate the virtual environment from folder "newprj" before installing the modules: `venv\Scripts\activate`.
Next you will see: "(venv) C:\Users\Basir Payenda\PycharmProjects\newprj>"
Then try installing the packages again.

Comment: How do I do that? Should I run activate file in Scripts folder

Comment: Usually do it through the terminal in the IDE. Run this activate file from folder with project.

Comment: I am new in CS, one month. Please write that code thanks