# i have problem while connecting python to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

im trying to connect my python script to mysql, but any of the mysql python connectors does'nt work.

Here is part of my code:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="mydatabase"
)
```

and here is error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "type.py", line 1, in <module>
     import mysql.connector
   File "/root/mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
     import mysql.connector
 ImportError: No module named connector
```

Comment: Install module using pip command based on your python version.

Comment: Try these possible answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24272278/8291579
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import mysql.connector Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272223/import-mysql-connector-python). See the most upvoted answer rather than accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have Connector installed, I would recommend using `pip list` to see if it is or `pip install mysql-connector-python`.

This is a great resource: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html

Answer (score 0):

You can first check whether `mysqlconnector` is installed on your device or not. 
For this the simplest way is

- to write `import mysql.connector` on interactive mode and hit enter;
- if it doesn't give you error then your good.
- If it does,

  - then go to tools > open system shells >
  - type : `pip install mysql.connector` > press enter.
  - This is install the connector and try it again after it is installed.