# Visual Studio code Mysql connector pip error

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio, pip, mysql-connector

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

I used its code and it loaded successfully.Then I opened visual studio on the terminal

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

I used the code, but it gives an error

```
ImportError: No module named typing
```

please help

Comment: what version of python are you using

Comment: @KetZoomer python 3.9 says installed but not found when I want to learn python version

Answer (score 0):

use

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

and in your code

```
import mysql.connector
```

Comment: i run python 3.94 and run the pip again. but it is alt´ready installed, try to update pip

Comment: i run the code also in the terminal of vs code. the same result

Comment: try also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272223/importerror-no-module-named-mysql-connector-using-python2  or there are a lot more mysql conmctor like pymaysql and other try your luck with them

Comment: where else can I use mysql connector

Comment: first try the link in the comment and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Comment: pip does not update "from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named typing" returns error

Comment: pythona brings already pip withit, so i don't know,why you need another, but run the pip command from a terminal

Comment: I know it is, but visual studio also says that pip was not found when I did "pip install mysql-connector"

Comment: try pip install pymysql when that alsp fails you have a problem that maybe superuser can help you with

Comment: do I need to write "pip install pymysql" to the terminal

Comment: i have a seperate terminal but you can use also the terminal in vs code, both do work

Comment: can I use jupyter notebook?

Comment: i don't know,. if it has atgerminal why not give it a try, but is answered  because i use vs cpde and python

Comment: thank you for helping me and answering the questions that remain in my mind, I hope I get out of this :)