# No module named 'mysql.connector' - while successfully installed

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I have a Synology server with a user called "myuser".

I have installed mysql-connector-pyhon using the command:
sudo python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python

Now, I would like to run a simple python script with "import mysql.connector".
I get the error:
No module named 'mysql.connector'

If I run that script as root on the server, it works (and I can create a database, etc).

Comment: did you check are you in the correct venv via `pip freeze`

Comment: you might be able to find an answer to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24272223/14664861